# Can SQL join and authenticate in a query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've ran into a situation where I'm asked to join two tables. Both however are on a DirectAdmin server and belong to different users. (DirectAdmin prefixes SQL user names with DA user names).

Therefor I can't perform a 'regular' join, because there is always one of the users that is not allowed to SELECT on the other table. I can't add them either because of the prefixing, and diving deep into the system and manually adding a user via commandline is something I'd rather avoid.

So I was wondering if there was a way to perform a login within the query? I could not find anything, so probably not. But maybe somebody tried it before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you make your connection first, then you send your query through that, so you've already authenticated.

If the user that you have authenticated with doesn't have access to all the tables, then the query will fail.

You could I suppose either connect with a user that has access to both tables, or make multiple connections to the tables with users who have access to them, pull the data out somewhere else and then do the join, probably only viable for very small tables though.

Comment: Thanks, not the answer I was hoping for, but then I'll look into alternatives.